# Vacation Approvals Multiple requests into one request?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

Not 100% sure if this makes the most sense to try and do in SQL.

What I am trying to achieve, is drive Vacation Approvals through SharePoint Lists using Flow.

Currently I am able to get the data from our scheduling system with the requests as individual rows, however I need to present the request back as a single item.

For Example:

[image]

The reason why I need it like this is because when I use Flow to populate the sharepoint list, it seems to be 1:1 mapping from field to field per row.

Not opposed to creating additional tables or request ID system to join all these together.

Thanks in advance,

Craig

Comment: SQL 2016 is the version I am running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `STRING_AGG ()` is not yet available in SQL 2016 (even in SP2 CU8), you could achieve your desired result using  `STUFF ()`. Following is the example of same:

```
SELECT 
  [Name],
  STUFF((
            SELECT ', ' + Cast(ReqLine as varchar(5)) 
            FROM #YourTable as T2
            Where T1.[Name] =  T2.[Name]
            FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,''
        ) AS DateOfRequest,

    STUFF((
        SELECT ', ' + Cast(FromDate as varchar(11)) + ' to ' +  Cast(EndDate as varchar(11))
        FROM #YourTable  as T2
        Where T1.[Name] =  T2.[Name]
        FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,''
    ) AS From_to_EndDate,

    STUFF((
        SELECT ', ' + Cast(SchedCode as varchar(11)) 
        FROM #YourTable  as T2
        Where T1.[Name] =  T2.[Name]
        FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,''
    ) AS From_to_EndDate

FROM #YourTable T1
GROUP BY [Name]
```

Answer (score 0):

For 2017 you can use [`STRING_AGG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

**[DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8beb53050fc0db6e96bbc1d2ed3647ff)**

```
create table  #myTable 
([Name] varchar(64), 
 DateOfRequest date, 
 ReqLine int, 
 FromDate date, 
 EndDate date, 
 SchedCode char(2))

insert into #myTable
values
('BSMITH','20190911',1,'20190912','20190912','V8'),
('BSMITH','20190911',2,'20190914','20190915','V8')

select 
  [Name],
  string_agg(DateOfRequest,char(13)) as DateOfRequest,
  string_agg(ReqLine,char(13)) as ReqLine,
  string_agg(FromDate,char(13)) as FromDate,
  string_agg(EndDate,char(13)) as EndDate,
  string_agg(SchedCode,char(13)) as SchedCode
from #myTable
group by [Name]
```

This won't make your DateOfRequest unique, but if you *know* it will be the same for each *Name* then you can just select it, and add it to the group by

```
select 
    [Name],
    DateOfRequest,
    string_agg(ReqLine,char(13)) as ReqLine,
    string_agg(FromDate,char(13)) as FromDate,
    string_agg(EndDate,char(13)) as EndDate,
    string_agg(SchedCode,char(13)) as SchedCode
  from #myTable
  group by [Name], DateOfRequest
```

Comment: I think, `STRING_AGG` is not yet available in SQL 2016 (even in SP2 CU8)